# Using rpy2 package in Python: Rruntime Error was unhandled by user code

Tags: python, r, computer-vision, rpy2

I'm trying to create an r environment in python using the rpy2 package. I'm trying to create a GLRLM of a ROI I have extracted from an image. I had some problems getting the package to load, but I finally managed to do so. Now I get the following error when running the code:

`RuntimeError was unhandled by user code`

At this line:

`ro.r('glrlmatrix <- radiomics:::glrlm(tissue)')`

I'm suspecting it cannot find the function "glrlm". I tried running the code in R and it works fine. Anyone has an idea of what to do?

```
tissue = pd.DataFrame(rgbRoi[...,0])
rdf= pandas2ri.py2ri(tissue)
ro.globalenv['tissue'] = rdf
radiomics=importr("radiomics",lib_loc="C:/Users/nka/Documents/R/win-library/3.3");
ro.r('tissue <- as.matrix(tissue)')
ro.r('print(dim(tissue))')
ro.r('library(radiomics)')
ro.r('glrlmatrix <- radiomics:::glrlm(tissue)')
ro.r('glrlmatrix[0,]    <- 0')                           ### Assign zero value to first row which belongs to mask region
ro.r('glrlfeature       <- array(NA,dim=c(11,1))')
ro.r('glrlfeature[1,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_GLN(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[2,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_HGLRE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[3,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_LRE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[4,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_LRHGLE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[5,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_LRLGLE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[6,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_LGLRE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[7,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_RLN(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[8,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_RP(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[9,1]  <- radiomics:::glrlm_SRE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[10,1] <- radiomics:::glrlm_SRHGLE(glrlmatrix)')
ro.r('glrlfeature[11,1] <- radiomics:::glrlm_SRLGLE(glrlmatrix)')
glr = ro.r.matrix(ro.r('glrlfeature'))
glr = np.array(glr)
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing `radiomics:::glrlm` you are accessing the symbol `glrlm` in the namespace `radiomics` while it is not exported (use `::` to only access exported symbols). This should be working in R and when parsing/evaluating an R string with `ro.r`. However, symbols are generally not exported by an R package because they not meant to be accessed directly by regular users.

Also The message `RuntimeError was unhandled by user code` does not seem to originate from rpy2. Is this really all there is to report about the error ?

Beside this, you may considering migrating some of the R strings to Python
(if you think that this is helping with legibility):

```
# this is implicitly loading the R package
radiomics=importr("radiomics",
                  lib_loc="C:/Users/nka/Documents/R/win-library/3.3");
# the line below is then unnecessary because of the above
# ro.r('library(radiomics)')

# binding the symbol "tissue" in R's globalenv to the matrix conversion
# of the data frame of the same name can be written more like Python
# code:
base = importr("base")
tissue_mat = base.as_matrix(tissue)
ro.globalenv['tissue'] = tissue_mat
# the following should work, unless the R code in `radiomics::glrlm`
# cannot handle anonymous objects
glrlmatrix = radiomics.glrlm(tissue_mat)
# glrmatrix is a Python/rpy2 objects that also be used as a numpy array
# and modified in-place
# (see http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/numpy.html#from-rpy2-to-numpy)
```

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately that is the error I get returned.
I found my error. 
It was the conversion of my rgbRoi[...,0]. When scaling the pixel levels  using this it worked:
`grayLvl=8  Img=rgbRoi[...,0]`
 `m = (grayLvl-1)/Img.max()`´
`scaledImg = Img*m`
 `P=np.array(np.round(scaledImg))`
`tissue = pd.DataFrame(P)`
I also made the following changes to glrlm function
 `ro.r('glrlmatrix <- radiomics::glrlm(tissue,angle=0,n_grey=4)')`

Comment: I have added a note that may help with the integration of calls to R functions into codebase in Python.